# How can I access a constant outside a class in swift?

Tags: class, swift, scope

```
class myClass {
    let x = 0
}
```

How can I access the `x` constant outside `myClass`?

Comment: `var x` is an instance property, accessible, for instance, with `MyClass().x`. What you're probably looking for is a type property, which would be `class var x`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x` is not defined as a constant, but as a mutable instance property. In order to make it immutable (which is technically different than constant, but the result doesn't change) you have to use `let`.

That said, if it's an instance property, you need a class instance, because the property is created as part of the class instantiation:

```
let instance = MyClass()
instance.x
```

If you want to make it a static property, accessible with the type and not with an instance of it, you should declare it as static:

```
class MyClass {
    static let x = 0
}
```

However static stored properties are available in swift 1.2 only.

For previous versions you can either use a computed property:

```
    class var x: Int { return 0 }
```

or turn the class into a struct:

```
struct MyClass {
    static let x = 0
}
```

An alternative solution is to use a nested struct:

```
class MyClass {
    struct Static{
        static let x = 0
    }
}

MyClass.Static.x
```

Comment: thanks I edited, meant to write 'let."  What is the rationale behind the variable of an instance of a class being accessible yet the class itself not?

Comment: Not sure I've caught your question... could you reformulate it?

Comment: It just seems semantic to have to create a generic instance just to get a variable out, I was just wondering if there was a reason behind this.  Also how would I call a variable that is in a function within a class, the . notation doesn't seem to work even with an instance created, i.e. instance.function.x doesn't give me x?

Comment: Think of a AddressBook class, with name and phone as fields. You have to create an instance of the class to store John's number, and you need that instance to retrieve his number. Accessing a phone number from the AddressBook class type can't tell you what's John's number. The AddressBook class is just a blueprint - a blueprint doesn't know how many time it's been used to create instances of it. But you can specify data relevant to the blueprint itself (such as sizes), which in out comparison are static fields: they apply to the type as a whole and not to an individual instance.

Comment: Thanks Antonio, that's a great analogy, I get it!  Could you look at my edited code above?  Why does sportResult.selectedSport return nil?

Comment: You should avoid changing questions so heavily - that invalidates all answers to the original questions, and readers can be confused and/or start downvoting answers because they are not relevant to the question. I suggest leaving the original question and add an update at bottom of it, or just create a new one if the topic is not strictly relevant to the original question

Answer (score 1):

You could declare it as static var, like this:

```
class MyClass {
   static var x = 0
}
```

and then you can access it outside the class with `MyClass.x`. If you declare it "class var", it will give you error message "Class stored properties not yet supported in classes; did you mean 'static'?", so they probably will be part of the language later. At this moment, you should do computed properties for class:

```
class MyClass {
   static var x: Int {
       return 3
   } 
} // This actually makes no sense to be a computed property though
```

You can find some info about Type Properties at: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html

Comment: static stored properties for classes are available in swift 1.2 (beta) - in earlier versions that results in a compilation error (as you noted)

Comment: It actually gives me that error using Swift 1.2 on Xcode 6.3 (Beta) Playground :s

Comment: If you use `class var x = 0`, yes, that doesn't compile - `static` works instead, but only in 1.2

Comment: using this simple example worked in playground, but when I try to apply to my UIPickerView (see edited code), I can't get the value?